# Как я могу проверять, не заходит ли мой куб за границы, пока движется влево и вправо свайпами? (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Мой куб всегда движется прямо. Свайпами я перемещаю его влево и вправо. Как я могу проверить, что вовремя движения влево-вправо, куб не заходит за границы платформ? Коллайдеры по краям ставить не очень хочется, так как очень много левелов. Можно ли это сделать с помощью райкаста? + нужно учитывать, что мой куб делает поворот и позиция поворота Y меняется, значит, позицию по X нужно чекать глобально. Может есть у кого мысли как это всё симпатично сделать?

Для движения использую следующий код:

```
private void Update()
{
    SwerveDir();
    StraightDir();
}

private void SwerveDir()
{
    float swerveAmount = Time.deltaTime * swerveSpeed * playerInputSystem.MoveFactorX; //MoveFactorX - свайп влево-вправо
    Vector3 swerveNewPosition = Vector3.right * swerveAmount;

    swerveAmount = Mathf.Clamp(swerveAmount, -maxSwerveAmount, maxSwerveAmount);

    transform.Translate(swerveAmount, 0, 0);
}

private void StraightDir()
{
    float straightAmount = Time.deltaTime * straightSpeed;
    transform.Translate(0, 0, straightAmount);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Какой код используйте для движения?

Comment: @AimonZ. добавила фрагмент кода в описание вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Ограничьте перемещение по боковой оси с помощью [Mathf.Clamp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html)

Пример:

```
private void StraightDir()
{
    float straightAmount = Time.deltaTime * straightSpeed;
    straightAmount = Mathf.Clamp(straightAmount, leftBoundPosition, rightBoundPosition);
    transform.Translate(0, 0, straightAmount);
}
```

Comment: мои платформы будут не одинакового размера, некоторые будут намного уже и тут уже ограничение по позиции не сработает

Comment: Изменяйте границы в зависимости по какой платформе проежает Ваш куб

Comment: как это сделать, подскажите пожалуйста. И у меня есть, например, платформа с поворотом, она изогнутая, а не прямая

Answer (score 0):

Вообще не понимаю нежелания ставить коллайдеры.

Если это делалось в 3д редакторе - то просто удалить нижнюю и верхнюю грани "дорожки" и заимпортить в проэкт вместе с самой дорожкой. Потом вешаешь на эти боковые стенки меш коллайдер и убираешь рендерер и размещаешь прямо над самой дорожкой.

Это в 100 раз быстрее и проще любого иного решения.